# Edit track name of track without changing filename

Tags: itunes

If you edit Name of a file in iTunes, the filename changes too, not just the tag. Is there a way to avoid this? I want top preserve the original filename untouched when I edit Name. Is there a simple easy-to-install malware-less 3rd party tool for this?

Answer (score 1):

It was easier than expected... within iTunes itself, in Preferences→Advanced, there is an option "Keep iTunes Media folder organised". Uncheck it and iTunes will leave the filenames as is.